Arduino Nano freezes at random times when motor is connected
I am to run a motor and control it with an Arduino Nano. I want to send signals to the nano with the usage of an nrf24l01. The correct use is that by default the motor will spin at a certain speed and when the joystick from the controller goes up the speed will decrease. I have achieved that however at random times the Arduino Nano froze completely requiring a reset. The components that I use are the following: nrf24l01 for the receiver, IRF540N for the mosfet to control the speed of the motor, 1N5819 as a flyback diode, a 9v battery pack to power just the motor since the Arduino is powered by my PC and the motor is a simple small motor 3-6 V. This is how it looked
To solve that issue I tried to move the ground connection of the 9v pack to the other gnd terminal of the nano (pin 04) which seemed to work or at least make the nano freeze less (I am not sure if it solved the issue). But when I do this I face a different issue at random times the motor reduces the max speed by itself. I am guessing I have done something wrong with the connections of the circuit if anyone can explain to me why these malfunctions happen I would highly appreciate it. Following is the code that I use
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
RF24 radio(8, 10);  // CE, CSN pins
const byte address[6] = "00001";
struct DataPacket {
 int number1;
 int number2;
 bool turnedon;
};
DataPacket receivedData;
const int dcmotor1 = 5;  // Forward 1
bool turnedon = false;
int state = -1;
void setup() {
 //initiate the motors
 Serial.begin(9600);
 radio.begin();
 radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);  // Set the same address as the transmitter
 radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
 radio.startListening();
 pinMode(dcmotor1, OUTPUT);

 //Serial.print("Setup Complete");
 }
 void loop() {

 if (radio.available()) {
  radio.read(&receivedData, sizeof(receivedData));
 if (receivedData.turnedon == 1) {
  //Serial.print("Received Number 1: ");
  Serial.println(receivedData.number1);
  //Serial.print("Received Number 2: ");
  Serial.println(receivedData.number2);
  if ((receivedData.number1 <= 1023 && receivedData.number1 > 1015) && (receivedData.number2 <= 520 && receivedData.number2 > 510)) {
    if (state != 1) {

      for (int x = 225; x >= 165; x -= 5) {
        analogWrite(dcmotor1, x);
        Serial.println(x);
        delay(50);
      }
      state = 1;
      Serial.print("State: ");
      Serial.println(state);
    }
  } else if ((receivedData.number1 <= 520 && receivedData.number1 > 510) && (receivedData.number2 <= 520 && receivedData.number2 > 510))  {
    if (state != 0) {
      for (int x = 165; x <= 225; x += 5) {
        analogWrite(dcmotor1, x);
        Serial.println(x);
        delay(50);
      }
      state = 0;
      Serial.print("State: ");
      Serial.println(state);
    }
    }
    }
    }

   }


try placing the MOSFET source connection between the Nano ground and the battery ground ... that way the motor current does not generate a voltage drop between the Nano ground connection and the mosfet source

your code is badly formatted  ... you should never see closing braces vertically aligned

Do you have an oscilloscope? Can you furnish some voltage traces?
